# code falling through on an if statement

Tags: c++

When I add the second if to test for car size M to calculateTotalCarCharge then try to test the condition of c, I'm getting an answer for m (77.28 & 167.44) when I really want (68.73 & 148.92), its almost like the code is somehow falling through to the next condition

Test conditions

```
Type - Days - Amount
C - 3 - 68.73
M - 3 - 77.28
C - 7 - 148.92
M - 7 - 167.44
```

```
#include <iostream> //for I/O
#include <iomanip> //for formatting output
#include <cmath>    //for math


using namespace std;

//prototypes
char validateCarChoice();
void displayProgramDescription();
int validateNumEntry(string prompt);
double calculateTotalCarCharge (char carSize, int daysRented);


//global constants
const char COMPACT = 'C';
const char MID = 'M';
const char FULL = 'F';
const char SUV = 'S';
const double COMPACT_DAILY_CHARGE = 22.91;
const double MID_DAILY_CHARGE = 25.76;
const double FULL_DAILY_CHARGE = 28.87;
const double SUV_DAILY_CHARGE = 98.88;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Description:
// Input parameter:
// Returns:
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main() 
{
    //local constants
    const string ENTER_DAYS_RENTED = "Enter the number of days rented: ";
    const string ENTER_MILES_DRIVEN = "Enter number of miles driven: ";

    //local variables
    char userCarTypeChosen;
    char carSize;
    int daysRented;
    double milesDriven;
    double carCharge;


//call function to display program description
displayProgramDescription();

//calls function to validate the car choice input by user
userCarTypeChosen = validateCarChoice();

//if car type chosen is suv (S) then only prompt will be to enter days
//rented, if not prompt both days rented and miles driven.
if (userCarTypeChosen == 'S')
{
    daysRented = validateNumEntry(ENTER_DAYS_RENTED);
}
else
{   
    daysRented = validateNumEntry(ENTER_DAYS_RENTED);
    milesDriven = validateNumEntry(ENTER_MILES_DRIVEN);
}

carCharge = calculateTotalCarCharge(carSize, daysRented);

   //to be removed
cout << carCharge;

    return 0;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Description: displayProgramDescription - displays program description
// Input parameter: N/A
// Returns: N/A
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void displayProgramDescription()
{
    //local constant
    const string PROGRAM_DESCRIPTION = "This program will calculate a car rental"
    " bill for Rent2U.";

    //displays program description
    cout << PROGRAM_DESCRIPTION << endl;    
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Description: validateCarChoice - displays menu of car options and daily cost.
//              Then error checks that a valid choice was given
// Input parameter: N/A
// Returns: letter of car chosen
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

char validateCarChoice ()
{
    //local constants

    const string ENTER_CAR_LETTER = "Enter letter for car size rented: ";
    const string ERROR_CAR_INPUT = "Re-enter letter for car size rented: ";

    //local variable
    char carSize;

    //displays car size options

    cout << "Car sizes:" << endl << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << "C - Compact size at $ 22.91 per day" << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << "M - Mid size at $ 25.76 per day" << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << "F - Full size at $ 28.76 per day" << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << "S - SUV at $ 98.88 per day" << endl << endl;

    //prompt for user input
    cout << ENTER_CAR_LETTER;
    cin >> carSize;
    carSize = toupper(carSize);

    //validation of car type chosen
    while (carSize !='C' && carSize !='M' && carSize !='F' && carSize !='S')
    {
  cout << ERROR_CAR_INPUT;
  cin >> carSize;
  carSize = toupper(carSize);       
    }

    return carSize;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Description: validateNumEntry - validates that the user entry is at least 1
// Input parameter: prompt- prompts user to enter number
// Returns: the user inputed number
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int validateNumEntry (string prompt)
{
    //local constant
    const string ERROR = "Error - entry must be at least 1.";

    //local variable
    double num;

    cout << prompt;
    cin >> num;


    while (num < 1)
    {
        cout << ERROR << endl;
        cout << prompt;
        cin >> num; 
    }

    return num;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Description:
// Input parameter:
// Returns:
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

double calculateTotalCarCharge (char carSize, int daysRented)
{
    //local constant
    const int WEEK = 7;
    const double LOWER_WEEK_RATE = 6.5;

    //local variable
    double totalCarCharge;
    int wholeWeek;
    int extraDays;


    if (carSize = 'C')
    {
        if (daysRented < WEEK)
        {
            totalCarCharge = (COMPACT_DAILY_CHARGE * daysRented);
        }
        else
        {
            wholeWeek = (daysRented / WEEK);
            extraDays = (daysRented % WEEK);
            totalCarCharge = ((wholeWeek * LOWER_WEEK_RATE * 
            COMPACT_DAILY_CHARGE) + (extraDays * COMPACT_DAILY_CHARGE));
        }
    }

    //once i add this if condition, if I try and test C I get the calculations
    //for M
    if (carSize = 'M')
    {
        if (daysRented < WEEK)
        {
            totalCarCharge = (MID_DAILY_CHARGE * daysRented);
        }
        else
        {
            wholeWeek = (daysRented / WEEK);
            extraDays = (daysRented % WEEK);
            totalCarCharge = ((wholeWeek * LOWER_WEEK_RATE * MID_DAILY_CHARGE) 
            + (extraDays * MID_DAILY_CHARGE));
        }
    }

    return totalCarCharge;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps using *two* `==` would be a better idea ...

Comment: That's a lot of code to sift through, and it requires user interaction. I suggest you reduce it to a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org); it's a very useful skill, and there's a good chance you'll find the bug yourself along the way.

Comment: Specifically `if (carSize = 'C')` and `(carSize = 'M')`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you are assigning in your if statement in `(carSize = 'C') and (carSize = 'M')`. Out of interest, why not opt for a `switch` on the char here? It seems the branches are mutually exclusive, and you aren't mutating `carSize` in the branches? This might help avoid this kind issue in future:

```
switch (carSize)
{
    case 'C':
       if (daysRented < WEEK)
        ...
       break;
    case 'M':
       // ...
 }
```

**Edit**

There is a second bug in your code, in that you are assigning:

```
userCarTypeChosen = validateCarChoice();
```

But then you are passing the uninitialized variable `carSize` to the `calculateTotalCarCharge` function:

```
carCharge = calculateTotalCarCharge(carSize, daysRented);
```

You should change the assignment to carSize

```
carSize = validateCarChoice();
```

and then remove the `userCarTypeChosen` variable entirely.

Comment: I've set carSize == 'C' and carSize == 'M' run the calculations and get 0. Made it into a switch statement and calculation is 0

Comment: There is a second bug - I've updated my answer.

Comment: is it okay to have 2 variables named carSize? one in validateCarChoice and one in main? So I can still use userCarTypeChosen if I pass that to calculateTotalCarCharge instead of carSize right?

Comment: Yes, indeed - variables are scoped to the function / method they are defined in.

Comment: ok thanks! I'll take a look more tonight

Answer (score 1):

For checking condition you have to use:

`if (carSize == 'M')`
and
`if (carSize == 'C')`.

Because when you use the statement:

`if (carSize = 'M')` will just assign value `carSize` to `'M'`

and will execute code inside the if statement. 
This condition is same for `if (carSize = 'C')` too.

OR use switch statement:

```
switch (carSize)
{
    case 'C':
       if (daysRented < WEEK)
        ...
       break;
    case 'M':
       // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In these comparisons to literals, a good idea can be to reverse the operands, which will throw a compiler error if you use single equal instead of double equal.

```
if (var == 'C')  // compiles, runs correctly
if (var = 'C')   // compiles, runs incorrectly, results in stackoverflow question
if ('C' == var)  // compiles, runs correctly
if ('C' = var)   // does not compile, fix this problem immediately
```

Comment: I've update it to carSize == 'C' and carSize =='M' and now the calculation is 0